# XML pulled into dataset excludes some elements

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, atom-feed

Here's the code I'm using to pull the xml from a webservice:

```
 string ServerURl = "xxX"   
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerURl);
 request.ContentType = "application/xml+atom";
 request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 var datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(datastream);
 ds.ReadXml(reader);
```

There are two types of elements that get returned formatted like:

```
<m:table>
   <d:Identification m:type="Edm.Int32">12346</d:Identification>
   <d:EmployeePhone m:type="Edm.Int32">123456</d:EmployeePhone>
   <d:EmployeeName>Joe Doe</d:EmployeeName>
```

I noticed all the rows with the **m:type** don't get returned, how do I include those as well?

Comment: Can you include a bit more information?  What does the XML look like before it is sent from the web service?  What are the contents of `response`?  What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Everything gets included.  It may be in another table.  Tables are two dimension objects and your xml parses into more than two dimensions.  The tags in your case becomes the columns and the innertext the data under the columns.  There is no room for the attributes in a single table so  another table is created.